# Build apk failed with cordova

Tags: java, android, html, cordova

I started to make an application with the command in the cordova command line, but encountered a problem like in the picture ..
please the instructions, Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Please don't post text as image. Edit your question to include the (indexable) text content and remove the image.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova for Android requires the Android SDK.
You need to install Android Build tools to run the app. Please follow the steps mentioned here https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/